# Can I specify child entity default ordering with Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For example, with the following classes

```
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}
```

And context

```
public class TempContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

How could I ensure that the objects in Parent.Children are ordered by Value

```
        TempContext tc = new TempContext();            
        var parents = tc.Parents.ToList();

        foreach (var p in parents)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Parent : {0}", (object) p.Name);
            foreach (var c in p.Children)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Child : {0} - {1}", c.Value, c.Description);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
```

Obviously, I can sort p.Children above before iterating the collection but I'd like the collection to already be ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must [write a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996438/how-to-sort-related-entities-with-eager-loading-in-ado-net-entity-framework) for that. Ordering is not managed by mapping.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this ability will be added to EF at some point.  I did notice the linked post was from 2009.  I assume one of the EF CTP's haven't added this capability.