# Oracle, Linq and sorting children

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC3 and EF 4.1 (Oracle DB). Let's suppose I have:

```
Public Class Parent
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Overridable Property Children As List(Of Child)
End Class

Public Class Child
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

I want to retrieve all parents from the database and for each parent I can access its children.

I want to do the following:

```
Dim firstParent = (From q In db.Parents Select q).First()

For Each child In firstParent.Children
    'Do something
Next
```

The problem is that I would like to enumerate the children from the youngest to the oldest. Is it possible without the client-side sorting? If yes then how can I achieve that? I know how I could achieve what I want with an SQL query, but I cannot make it work with LINQ...

EDIT:
Since this seems not to have a solution in my case and sorting everytime I request data is not an option, maybe there is something I can do when I insert the data to the database? I do not have a control on which order EF saves items to the database when I call db.Save(), but maybe there is some syntax I could use to require ordering based on some property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about approaching it from the other side

```
var children = db.Children.Where(c => c.ParentId == "foo").OrderBy(c => c.Age);
```

Hope you can convert this into vb.net

Comment: I am actually originally a C# programmer, so it is not a problem. The problem is that in the real case scenario I have 4-levels and i want them to be ordered correctly at each level...

Answer (score 0):

If you were using NHibernate you could define a [default order](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues) when loading child collections (using the "order-by" attribute). Since you are using Entity Framework, [there is no such mapping option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741714/can-i-specify-child-entity-default-ordering-with-entity-framework-code-first), so you could maybe create a specific Repository method (such as `ParentRepository.GetOrderedChildren(Parent myParent)`) and load your children using a LINQ join (this is the lambda syntax):

```
context.Parents
    .Join(context.Children,
        p => p,
        c => c.Parent,
        (p, c) => new { Parent = p, Child = c }
    )
    .Where(o => o.Parent == myParent)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Child.myOrderField)
    .Select(o => o.Child)
    .ToList();
```

Please note that your code may suffer from the [Select N+1 problem](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/SelectNPlusOne) since you are loading all your parents and then loading children for every parent. I suggest you to do some sort of [eager loading](http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/24/entity-framework-4-using-eager-loading/).