# How do I order an underlying child collection of a parent class in LINQ lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

For example:

```
_ctx.DataContext.Set<ParentClass>().Include("ChildCollection").OrderBy(...)
```

Everytime I put a Lambda expression in the OrderBy clause I can't get access to the properties off the ChildCollection property that I want the underlying child collection to be ordered by.  I don't want the parent class ordered by any specific column.

How do I achieve this using LINQ/Lambda expression?  Seems like it should be really easy!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort related entities with eager loading in ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996438/how-to-sort-related-entities-with-eager-loading-in-ado-net-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading is not able to order navigation properties. You must use something like this:

```
var query = _ctx.DataContext
                .Set<ParentClass>()
                .Select(p => new 
                   {
                      Parent = p,
                      Childs = p.ChildCollection.OrderBy(c => c.Something)
                   });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having big problems with you example solution. 
1) I need to return a non-anonymous type out of my repository.
2) The underlying collection is of type IList and so seems to barf when converting from IOrderedEnumerable. Struggling with this...

Comment: In such case you must define new type because as I know projection can't fill entity type.

Comment: Yes ordered enumerable can't be placed to list. You must have `IOrderedEnumerable` property in custom type.