# How to return IList from my repository with ordered queries in LINQ/EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern, ef-code-first

My repository layer has been working fine, exposing `IList<T>` for lists of things like `GetAll()` etc.  However, I tried to use `OrderBy` on one of my LINQ queries.  Then I ran into real big problems because the LINQ query cannot be converted to an `IList`.  It wants to return an `IOrderedEnumerable`.

This is a big problem because I want to keep my repo self contained and **NOT** expose `IQueryable` to my services.  Why should I change my repo architecture just because of an 'orderby'!

So, despite this I set about converting my repository layer to returning `IEnumerable` so that I can at least return sorted data.  I then ran into more problems because I then needed to convert my data classes to `IEnumerable` so I can map easily between my view model and data model classes.  (This is using AutoMapper).

Then I realised that code-first doesn't like `IEnumerable` and won't build relationships between tables if not defined using at least an `IList` (and am also told `ICollection`??).

So my question is what do I from here?  All I want to do is return data to the client (in this case the services), in an ordered fashion without changing return types all the way through my application.

Comment: It would help if you showed real code examples of what you are trying to do and which parts don't work.

Comment: You should also post link to your previous question where you got a solution which didn't satisfy you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487115/how-do-i-order-an-underlying-child-collection-of-a-parent-class-in-linq-lambda

Comment: Btw. `ICollection` is recommended because dynamic proxies are using `HashSet`.

Comment: Another story about evil entity framework breaking nice repository pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for instance works and it sorts and returns an `IList<T>`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public IList<Customer> GetSortedListOfCustomersInCity(string city)
{
    return context.Customers
        .Where(c => c.City == city)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
        .ToList();
}
```

(I think this is also what Reed Copsey in his answer meant.) I guess, your problem is of another kind, since it is too obvious that this example works. But I couldn't derive from your questions where exactly your issue is. A piece of your not working code is appreciated.

Comment: I tried putting everything back to IList so code-first registers the relationships.  I get the error "The entity or complex type 'CodeFirstNamespace.<theClass>' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.  I think this is because I am trying to project into a concrete data-model class.  Can I not still return my entity with it's child list sorted?

Comment: @Jon: I don't know. Everything would be easier to understand for all of us if you would show the code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is what do I from here? All I want to do is return data to the client (in this case the services), in an ordered fashion without changing return types all the way through my application.

When you create your queries, you can always return `results.ToList()`, which will evaluate them and convert them into an `IList<T>` for you.

This is, in many cases, advantageous if your query is an `IQueryable<T>` internally in any case, as it will fully evaluate the query, and prevent issues that can arise if you close your internal data context, then try to enumerate your results.

Comment: Thanks I will try that but I'm sure that this didn't work for me.