# Ordering parent's list of children

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As part of an MVC app I have two classes which map to the appropriate tables in my database

```
public class Child {
    public int id;
    public int parentId; //foreign key to parent class
    public int age;
}

public class Parent {
    public int id; 
    public virtual IList<Child> children;
}
```

In my controller I need to select only one parent by the id, including its list of children.

With the parent that gets selected, I want that parent's list of children to be in order of age.
I have been able to do this with the following code:

```
Parent parent = context.parents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == idToCheck);
parent.children = parent.children.OrderBy(c => c.age).Cast<Child>().ToList();
```

Even though this works, I am left with the feeling that this is a hackish way to do what I'm after.

From what I've read, it is not possible to order children when I initially select the parent. Is that correct?

Is there anything I am doing in the above code that could/should be done better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996438/how-to-sort-related-entities-with-eager-loading-in-ado-net-entity-framework

Comment: Yes that question does address this issue, however that solution relies on what is probably a side-effect of relationship Fix-up not something that is officially supported - I want to keep away from that. Is there anything wrong in the way I have done it?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if there is no matching parent and as a result you will get a `NullReferenceException` on the following line. To make it clearer that you always expect there to be a matching parent I suggest you use `First()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Torbjörn, I do check parent is not null further on,~ if (parent != null) I will put the line that orders children within that block.

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin or Single(), if you think there should only be a single match and want it to throw if for some reason there is more than 1. It seems like it's probably more appropriate here since it looks like that id is assumed to be unique.